# How to change the position of extension icons in Chromium 47?

Tags: chromium

I've noticed a new interface change in Chromium 47.

Extension icons are now shown in the menu.

Is there a way to revert this change?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can **resize** the extension icon bar.

Move the mouse cursor at the end of the *url bar* until it changes to a **double arrow cursor**, then *click and slide* the cursor to the left.

One problem is that you will end up with a very tiny url bar. So this might not be a solution for you.

Comment: I'm aware of the resizing option. Thanks! My question was more on if I can revert this new "feature" that displays all extension icons in the menu. This was not the case in previous versions of Chromium.